# Sensu subdue alerts outside working hours and weekends

Tags: attributes, sensu

I want to subdue some sensu checks outside working hours and weekends. The documentation is not clear on how it works. [Sensu subdue documentation](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/checks.html#subdue-attributes)

```
        'subdue' => {
        'days' => {
            'all' => [
                {
                    'begin' => '8:00 PM',
                    'end' => '10:00 AM'
                }
            ],
            'saturday' => [
                {
                    'begin' => '12:00 AM',
                    'end' => '11:59 PM'
                }
            ],
            'sunday' => [
                {
                    'begin' => '12:00 AM',
                    'end' => '11:59 PM'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

My question is: will the specific day override the all attribute?
Also: is there a better way to do this check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Specific day override **all** attribute. We should add subdue configurations in our **client.json** file.